# How to delete a variation in SP2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, variations

In sp2013, I have a variation label I want to delete. Is the process to go to variation settings and to delete the label, or do I need to delete the sites first and then delete the label?

Answer (score 1):

To delete the variation label, you could go to the site settings->Site Collection Administration->Variation labels->Delete the variation label.

If you delete the variation label in the Variation labels list, then the variation will no longer reflect any changes or additions you make to the source site.

You can still use the site for other purposes. If you want to delete the site, you could delete the site.

Comment: I read there are two hidden lists that stores variation data. So I need to then go in them to delete the entries in there after?

Comment: Also some sites say when u delete the label, it deletes the sites automatically, and if that process times out (if say there were a lot of sites), it will result in an error.

Comment: Per my test in my SharePoint 2013 environment, the site will not be deleted automatically when you delete the variation label in the variation label list.